# Finding proper subsequence

Tags: algorithms

I'm preparing for CS201 exam and I stumbled upon an interesting problem.

Input: 
A sequence of random positive and negative integers (up to 1.0000).

Output:
A **contiguous (to be clear: subsequence of consecutive elements)** subsequence of the original sequence, such that after its reversal in the original sequence the balance will remain nonnegative. The  contiguous subsequence must be as small as possible.

A few examples:

Example 1.

> Input:
>
> > 3 -4 -2 3 (-4 is the point, where the balance is negative, because 3 + (-4) = -1)
>
> Output:
>
> > -4 -2 3 (the contiguous subsequence to be rotated)
>
> because:
>
> > 3 3 -2 -4 (now: 3 + 3 = 6; 6-2 = 4; 4-4 = 0. The balance is always positive.)

Now there is no point, where balance is negative.

Example 2.

> Input:
>
> > 3 -5 2 -1 (3+(-5)=-2, so the balance is negative at -5)
>
> Output:
>
> > Impossible to find a subsequence to rotate.

Example 3.

> Input:
>
> > 4 -4 -3 5 2 -4 5 -2 (4 + (-4) = 0; 0 + (-3) = -3. The balance is negative at -3.)
>
> Output:
>
> > 4 -4 -3 5 2
>
> Because:
>
> > 2 5 -3 -4 4 -4 5 -2 (2+5=7;7+(-3)=4;4+(-4)=0;0+4=4;4+(-4)=0;0+5=5;5+(-2)=3. The balance is always positive.)

I had multiple approaches to this problem, but none of them cover all possible cases.

Comment: Try to characterise hopeless cases. What subsequences of length 2 make the biggest difference if reversed? What subsequences of length $n+1$? $n+2$?

Comment: @greybeard do you mean the algorithms should (naively) swap all subsequences of (n, n+1) and check the balance, then (n, n+1, n+1) and check the balance and so on?

Comment: I tried to make you consider one particular paradigm. (And consider the value of the middle element of odd-size subsequences in reversal.)

Comment: Ok! I presume, that the middle element of odd-size sequences is a pivot? I'm not certainly sure what paradigm do you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "balance"? Does a subsequence have to be consecutive?

Comment: @DavidRicherby This should be definitely clarified. By the balance I mean that after choosing the subsequence, then reverting it and putting back to the sequence there will be no situations, that the sum will be negative at some point (summing from the beginning). Please take a look at examples one more time. I extended them to provide more clarification.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question.  A subsequence is normally defined to be a subset that does not have to be consecutive.  However in your examples, the subsequence you output is always a consecutive range of numbers.  Did you really mean consecutive range; or did you really mean consecutive? Please edit the question to clarify, if you actually meant they must be consecutive.  Examples are not a substitute for a clear problem statement; the problem statement should be unambigous on its own, without having to look at examples to understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I clarified the question. The subsequence must be obviously **contiguous**. Sorry I didn't mentioned it before.

Comment: In example 3, shouldn't the output be : -3, 5? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TomDavies92 Actually, it wasn't obvious at all, which is why I asked. The [general definition of "subsequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) in mathematics (as, for example, used in the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem) is _not_ contiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my answer is exactly the same as Lurr's, but I'm not sure if I should edit it.

Suppose the subsequence is $(l,r]$ and $b[i]$ is the balance at $i$-th position. If $i\notin (l,r]$, $b[i]$ won't change. Otherwise $(l,i]$, i.e. the first $i-l$ elements of $(l,r]$ is replaced by the last $i-l$ elements of $(l,r]$, which is $(r-i+l,r]$. Therefore, $b'[i]=b[l]+b[r]-b[r-i+l]$, where $b'$ is the balance of new sequence. Note that there's a bijection between $b'[i]$ and $b[r-i+l]$. It means $b'$ is non-negative iff:

1. $\forall i \notin (l,r], b[i]\ge 0$
2. $\forall i \in (l,r], b[l]+b[r]\ge b[i]$

Note that we can rewrite the second property as $b[l]+b[r]\ge max_{i\in(l,r]} b[i]$.

Let $L$ denote the rightmost position s.t. $b[i]\ge 0$ for all $i\le L$ and $R$ denote the leftmost position s.t. $b[i]\ge 0$ for all $i>R$. We need $l\le L$ and $r\ge R$ to satisfy the first constraint. We implicitly assume these constraints in all the following statements so we only need to care about the second constraint. We need three more observations:

- If $(l,r]$ is valid, for all $l'\le l$ we don't need to care about $(l',r']$ where $r'>r$.
- For all $r<r'$, if $b[r]\ge b[r']$, $(l,r]$ is better than $(l,r']$.
- Fix $l$. If $b[r']$ is the largest in $[R,r']$ and $(l,r']$ is invalid, $\forall r<r'$ $(l,r]$ is also invalid.

The first observation is trivial since we need the shortest subsequence. The second observation is obvious since $b[l]+b[r]$ is larger, $(l,r]$ is shorter and the constraint is looser. The condition of the third observation follows the second: if $b[r']$ is not the largest, there exists a better $r$. Now let's see why $(l,r']$ is invalid: $b[l]+b[r']<max_{i\in(l,r']} b[i]$. Since $b[l]$ is non-negative and $b[r']$ is the largest, this can only happen if $b[l]+b[r']<max_{i\in(l,R-1]} b[i]$.So $\forall r<r'$, $b[l]+b[r]<max_{i\in(l,R-1]} b[i]$, which means $(l,r]$ is invalid. Now the flow is clear:

1. Maintain a monotone candidate list of $r$ based on the second observation. Also, maintain $max_{i\in(l,r]} b[i]$ for all $r$ in order to check the second constraint. Preprocessing takes $O(n)$.
2. Iterate $l$ from $L$ to $1$:
3. If the largest $r$ is invalid, the smaller candidates are also invalid according to the third observation. Skip this $l$.
4. If the largest $r$ is valid, check if the second largest candidate $r'$ is also valid. If so, discard $r$ according to observation one and check again*. Otherwise, smaller candidates are also invalid so $r$ is optimal for $l$. Update the answer if $(l,r]$ is better. *Although this step is a loop, it discards an element of $r$ when it repeats, so the total complexity is still $O(n)$.

Finally we solve the problem in $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest “integrating” sequence. i.e. building balance sequence. It's funny, but when contiguous subsequence of original sequence gets reversed, corresponding segment of balance sequence plot gets literally rotated for 180 degrees. It means subsequence reversion will remove all negative balance points iff:

1. Subsequence contains all negative balance points inside;
2. Balance inside subsequence is never greater then sum of balances
       at the beginning (before first element) and the end (after last
       element) of subsequence. (All points where it’s greater will become
       negative after rotation.)

It's possible to find shortest subsequence which follows this requirements in $O(n)$.

Keep in mind that any element can be first in the sequence only if balance right before it, is greater than at any point between chosen element and first point where balance goes negative. (Or we can make shorter subsequence starting from this point with bigger sum of balance at the beginning and end.) All such elements form a monotonically decreasing subsequence. And there is corresponding monotonically increasing subsequence of possible last elements. And for each possible first element we need to find only first corresponding possible last element and it is never smaller then possible last element corresponding to the previous first element.